# Altium signal integrity not analyzed

Tags: altium, signal-integrity

I am new to signal integrity, when I try SI in Altium the model assignments is showing the status as passed and getting the waveforms, when I do Reanalyse design it is showing as not analysed and no waveforms are coming.